# Is there a way to view your app's .entitlements file from your app's .ipa archive?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6, ad-hoc-distribution, archiving

I think there's an issue with my app's .entitlements file when a .ipa is created and so I want to check the Bundle ID of the entitlements file. There's a fairly complicated build script I am using to change some stuff in there before building so I want to see what the final product is. I know that there used to be an Entitlements.plist that I could get off of the ipa but it doesn't seem to be there any longer. Is there any way to access the .entitlements file now?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, unzip the `.ipa` file which will create a Payload directory.  Inside of the Payload directory is the application package.  Right-click the app package in Finder to "Show Package Contents".

Look for the embedded.mobileprovision file which you can open with a text editor or plist editor.  Look for the `<key>Entitlements</key>`

Comment: My embedded.mobileprovision file just shows a bunch of numbers and no text at all. Is there some other step I need to take to make that human readable?

Comment: The format should be a property list - just verified with one of my ipa's.

Comment: Is your ipa recent? I am fairly certain they used to be plists in the past. I tried renaming my embedded.mobileprovision file to a plist and I got told it was corrupted when I tried to open it. When looking at the 'Kind' of file it was with Get Info, Apple says it's a 'Developer Provisioning Profile.'

Comment: Yes, I just went through this process on an app submitted and accepted in the last 2 weeks.

Comment: If you're using Sublime Text, just reopen with encoding -> UTF-8

Comment: Or just select the file in finder, and press Spacebar to preview it.

Answer (score 33):

For those getting here via Google, the Information Apple provides at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1798/_index.html is a lot more recent.
Specifially, after unzipping the IPA:

Display the entitlements in the app by running:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- "Payload/YourApp.app"
```

and display the provisioning profile by running:

```
security -D -i "Payload/YourApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision"
```

Comment: in my case 'security -D -i' did not work, I had to use 'security cms -D -i' instead

Comment: The `codesign` command doesn't seem to work anymore with Big Sur

Comment: The `codesign` command worked for me on Ventura (macOS `13.5.2`)